# Unable to adjust brightness Lenovo Tab3

Tags: lenovo, screen-brightness

My brand new Lenovo Tab3 doesn't respond to screen brightness slider at all. Nor does the automatic adjustment work when ambient light changes. Any similar experiences or maybe solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.
Turns out you have to accept the Lenovo customer-whatever and register when first installing the tab to get full functionality. The device is usable without registration, but there seem to be a few functions missing.

Comment: Mine did not work as well. Do I need to reset it to make it work?

Comment: Factory reset, then start from beginning. Register to the customer program. And post this sort of follow-up questions as a comment, not an answer.